# Is there a Python test framework suitable to run simulations

Tags: python, functional-testing

I am looking into characterising some software by running many simulations with different parameters.

Each simulation can be assimilated to a test with different input parameters.

The test specification lists the different parameters:

```
param_a = 1
param_b = range(1,10)
param_c = {'package_1':1.1, 'params':[1,2,34]}
function = algo_1
```

and that would generate a list of tests:

```
['test-0':{'param_a':1, 'param_b':1, param_c:},
 'test-1':{'param_a':1, 'param_b':2, param_c:},
 ...]
```

and call the function with these parameters. The return value of the function is the test results that should be reported in a 'friendly way'.

```
test-0: performance = X%, accuracy = Y%, runtime = Zsec ...
```

For example, Erlang's Common Test and Quickcheck are very suitable for this task, and provide HTML reporting of the tests.

Is there anything similar in Python?

Comment: Could you edit the question to show what you want the result to be? Currently it isn't legal code. Edit: by the result, I meant the list of tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the lack of available packages, here is the implementation of a couple of different wanted features:

- test definition:

a python file that contain a `config` variable which is a dictionary of static requirements and a `variables` variable which is a dictionary of varying requirements (stored as lists).

```
config = {'db' : 'database_1'}

variables = {'threshold' : [1,2,3,4]}
```

The test specification is import using `imp`, through parsing the arguments of the script into args:

```
testspec = imp.load_source("testspec", args.test)
```

- test generation:

The list of tests are generated using a modified version of `product` from `numpy`:

```
def my_product(dicts):
    return (dict(izip(dicts, x)) for x in product(*dicts.itervalues()))
def generate_tests(testspec):
    return [dict(testspec.config.items() + x.items()) for x in my_product(testspec.variables)]
```

which returns:

```
[{'db': 'database_1', 'threshold': 1},
 {'db': 'database_1', 'threshold': 2},
 {'db': 'database_1', 'threshold': 3},
 {'db': 'database_1', 'threshold': 4}]
```

- dynamic module loading:

To load the correct module `database_1` under the generic name `db`, I used again `imp` in combination with the `testspec` in the class that uses module:

```
dbModule = testspec['db']
global db
db = imp.load_source('db', 'config/'+dbModule+'.py')
```

- pretty printing:

not much here, just logging to terminal.

Answer (score 3):

you could give [Robot Framework](http://robotframework.org/) a chance. It will be easy/native to call your Python code from Robot test cases. We will get nice [HTML reports](https://blog.codecentric.de/files/2012/04/impression_logfile.png) as well. If you get blocked you will get some help on SO (tag [robotframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/robotframework)) or on the [Robot User Mailing List](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/robotframework-users).

Comment: for the test case generation, it doesn't look like Robot framework will be useful. But I will look into their report capabilities.